# Iterative solution to reverse linked list in sets of k

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Given a singly linked list, i am trying to reverse k nodes at a time through out the list.
So, if k = 2, **1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6** will turn into **2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 3 -> 6 -> 5**. It is assumed that k is always a factor of the length of the list (Length of the list is divisible by k).

I am trying to solve this using an **iterative approach** rather than a recursive one. I am trying to parse the list as sets of k nodes and reverse them each till the end of the list. This is my code

```
def reverseList(A, B): # param A : head node of linked list, param B : integer, return the head node in the list
    if B < 2:
        return A
    dummy = ListNode('dummy')
    dummy.next = A
    prev, behind = dummy, A
    while behind:
        ahead = behind
        for i in range(B-1):
            ahead = ahead.next
        new_behind = reverse_list(behind, ahead)
        prev.next = ahead
        behind.next = new_behind
        behind = behind.next
    return dummy.next
```

The reverse_list function reverses the list from the start to end nodes of a k set and returns the node at the beginning of the new k set of nodes (the new start node)

```
def reverse_list(start, end):
    prev, curr = None, start
    while prev is not end:
        next = curr.next
        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
        curr = next
    return curr
```

The definition of ListNode class

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
```

When the values A = [ 6 -> 10 -> 0 -> 3 -> 4 -> 8 ] and B = 3 are given, the output is 8 -> 4 -> 3. What exactly am I missing or overlooking? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For each iteration, you should point the next node of the current node to the next node of the next node, then point the next node of the next node to the head node, and then point the head node to the next node, to complete a reversal of the give number of nodes. Then assign the current node as the new head, repeat the above, until the next node of the head is `None`:

```
def reverseList(A, B):
    head = A
    while head.next:
        node = head.next
        for _ in range(B - 1):
            next_node = node.next
            if next_node:
                node.next = next_node.next
                next_node.next = head.next
                head.next = next_node
        head = node
    return A
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/ElatedSurefootedFilesize

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the mistake i've been making. I didn't update the 'prev' pointer while updating the 'behind' pointer. It should have been

> prev = behind

After getting the behind and ahead pointers, this should be the block of code within the while loop in reverseList function

```
new_behind = reverse_list(behind, ahead)
prev.next = ahead
behind.next = new_behind
prev = behind
behind = behind.next
```